# Read inbox of 2nd account and running outlook on a server?

Tags: powershell, outlook

I have my own mailbox account plus another shared mailbox defined in outlook.
I need to access this 2nd mailbox via powershell.  How can I specify the other account?

Two questions:
(1) If I have a 2nd account added in outlook, how do I access that?

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application  
$OutlookInbox = $Outlook.session.GetDefaultFolder(6)  
$TotalEmailCount = $OutlookInbox.Items.Count

$TotalEmailCount
```

(2) Can I run a powershell script on a server if the script is executed as a domain user that is a local admin?

Answer (score 1):

The [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. For example, a VBA sample (the Outlook object model is common for all programming languages):

```
Sub ResolveName() 
  Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace  
  Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient  
  Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder  

  Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
  Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev")  
  myRecipient.Resolve  
  If myRecipient.Resolved Then  
    Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)  
  End If  
End Sub 

Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)  
  Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder  

  Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 
  CalendarFolder.Display  
End Sub
```

Also if you have already added a second account in Outlook you may consider using the [Stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.stores) property of the `Namespace` class which returns a `Stores` collection object that represents all the `Store`` objects in the current profile. The [Working with Outlook Accounts, Stores, Folders and Items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/05/31/outlook-accounts-stores-folders-items/) article provides sample code for dealing with multiple stores and folders. For example:

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application  
$OutlookInbox = $Outlook.session.Stores(1).GetDefaultFolder(6)  
$TotalEmailCount = $OutlookInbox.Items.Count

$TotalEmailCount
```

> Can I run a powershell script on a server if the script is executed as a domain user that is a local admin?

Outlook should be installed on the machine where you want to run the script.

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office?wa=wsignin1.0%3Fwa%3Dwsignin1.0) article. Possible alternatives are:

1. Exchange Web Services, see [Start using web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/start-using-web-services-in-exchange)
2. Extended MAPI
3. Any other third-party components designed for the server side excecution.

Comment: Had to swap the bracket types from Stores(1) to Stores[1], but this was what I needed